# How to get applescript to trigger on recieved email?

Tags: email, applescript

This is the first bit of scripting I have done.
I am trying to get an applescript to copy the body of an email and send it as an imessage.
I have this script set to fire with a rule in the mail app

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages matchmsgs for rule Alertrule
        tell application "Mail"
            set msg to item 1 of matchmsgs
            set msgcontent to (content of msg) as Unicode text
        end tell
        set the clipboard to msgcontent
    end perform mail action with messages
    tell application "Messages"
        
        set targetBuddy to "+12223334444"
        set targetService to (id of 1st account whose service type = iMessage)
        set textMessage to "ALERT: " & (the clipboard)
        
        set theBuddy to participant targetBuddy of account id targetService
        send textMessage to theBuddy
    end tell
end using terms from
```

the problem I am running into is that it doesn't seem to fire on the receive of an email that fits the rule.
When I right click on the email and select "apply rule" I can see the gear spinning on the top bar indicating that the script is running but it doesn't send the imessage.
If I then go to script editor and play the applescript it sends an imessage with the body of the email I ran the rule on.

So it seems like it works just not with the automation from mail rules.
anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the `Messages` part must be **inside** the `perform mail action` scope.

And the clipboard *detour* is not needed

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages matchmsgs for rule Alertrule
        set msg to item 1 of matchmsgs
        set msgcontent to (content of msg) as Unicode text
        
        tell application "Messages"
            
            set targetBuddy to "+12223334444"
            set targetService to (id of 1st account whose service type = iMessage)
            set textMessage to "ALERT: " & msgcontent
            
            set theBuddy to participant targetBuddy of account id targetService
            send textMessage to theBuddy
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: Other than the error correctly pointed out by user @vadian, all **conditions** (or at least one of them, depending on your choice) of the rule **must be satisfied**. If the conditions are indicated (by you) incorrectly, then the rule action will never run. At least, it will not run in the correct manner.

Comment: Thank you both, that solved my problem. I had the rule set to all messages as the condition for testing so I think it was my wacked out script that was the problem